# Static block is not being transpiled

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig, tsc, browserslist

I'm using Angular 14.x and in the tsconfig file:

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./xy",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "es2022",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
}
```

}

And a browserslist config in the package.json:

```
"browserslist": [
    "ios_saf >= 15.5",
    "Safari >= 15.6.1",
    "Firefox >= 102",
    "last 2 Edge versions",
    "last 2 Chrome versions"
]
```

According to this list https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_classes_static_initialization_blocks Safari doesn't support static blocks. So it should be transpiled by the Angular TSC, shouldn't it? But it's not getting transpiled.

I thought the TSC looks at the configured target (es2022) and takes in account what is defined in the browserslist and then transpiles the code and where need it transpiles it to something the configured browsers understand?

The code that should be transpiled:

```
export class XYZ {
  private static y: any;
  static {
    try {
        this.y = this.hello();
    } catch {
        this.y = 'unknown';
    }
  }

 static hello() {
    return 'hello';
}}
```

Comment: Isn't the browserlist only for CSS?

Comment: TypeScript does not transpile your code to earlier ECMAScript versions. It only strips the types. If you need transpilation across ECMAScript versions, use a proper transpiler like Babel.

Comment: @vr. Are you sure? I disagree: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target

Comment: @ThomasSablik It's severely limited in what it does transpile. For example, it won't polyfill newer features of the language. And yes, it does not polyfill static blocks. The target also tells TypeScript which library declaration files it needs. It's certainly not for transpilation like Babel.

Comment: @vr. Do you have a reference for your statement? My reference (the official docs) contain _"The target setting changes which JS features are downleveled and which are left intact."_ TypeScript was always able to transpile between ECMA versions, at least since 2016 I use it for exact this functionality.

Comment: Hmm, you are right, but it only seems to transpile *syntax*. It won't polyfill methods like `flatMap` or `String.raw`, although it will prevent you from using them if you set the target to <ES6. I'm not sure what "Angular TSC" is or what it does differently, though.

Comment: I'm aware of that tsc doesn't polyfill. But the static block can be transpiled to older versions. Something like this babel plugin does: https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-proposal-class-static-block

Comment: Not sure if this is correct?
TSC should transpile your code that is supported by the target browsers. However, the transpilation of static initialization blocks is a bit different.

The static block syntax is a relatively new addition to JavaScript (it was added in ECMAScript 2022), and not all browsers have implemented it yet. In fact, at the time of writing, only the latest versions of Safari support it. Because of this, the TSC does not transpile static blocks by default, even if your target and module options are set to a version of JavaScript that does not support them.