# Angular build error - Class static blocks are not supported yet

Tags: angular, build, esbuild

I am trying to do a production build of an application that was upgraded from Angular 8 to Angular 12. I am getting the following error when I try to build for production. How do I fix this?

```
Error: Optimization error [polyfills-es2015.b56008bea0cb81a74f51.js]: Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
polyfills-es2015.b56008bea0cb81a74f51.js:68:15: error: Class static blocks are not supported yet
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/shafkhan/Documents/MBiz/cms-management-web/user-management-web/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1493:15)
    at /Users/shafkhan/Documents/MBiz/cms-management-web/user-management-web/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1282:29
    at /Users/shafkhan/Documents/MBiz/cms-management-web/user-management-web/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:629:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (/Users/shafkhan/Documents/MBiz/cms-management-web/user-management-web/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:726:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/Users/shafkhan/Documents/MBiz/cms-management-web/user-management-web/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:596:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)

Error: Optimization error [polyfills-es5.566af3cf92b3657f00ee.js]: Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
polyfills-es5.566af3cf92b3657f00ee.js:1793:15: error: Class static blocks are not supported yet
    at failureErrorWithLog (/Users/shafkhan/Documents/MBiz/cms-management-web/user-management-web/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1493:15)
    at /Users/shafkhan/Documents/MBiz/cms-management-web/user-management-web/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1282:29
    at /Users/shafkhan/Documents/MBiz/cms-management-web/user-management-web/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:629:9
    at handleIncomingPacket (/Users/shafkhan/Documents/MBiz/cms-management-web/user-management-web/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:726:9)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (/Users/shafkhan/Documents/MBiz/cms-management-web/user-management-web/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:596:7)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
```

My Angular Version

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.18
Node: 14.21.3
Package Manager: npm 6.14.18
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 12.2.17

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.18
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.18
@angular-devkit/core            7.3.10
@angular-devkit/schematics      7.3.10
@angular/cli                    12.2.18
@angular/http                   7.2.16
@schematics/angular             12.2.18
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75757361/static-block-is-not-being-transpiled looks similar

Comment: Also, unsure when angular switched to esbuild or if it's even the default now, but it's been supported by esbuild for a couple of years: https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/pull/1729 so if you can switch to using esbuild maybe it may work out. See https://angular.io/guide/esbuild#using-the-browser-esbuild-builder

Answer (score 0):

I guess esBuild version you are having does not have `class static block` support. I found the issue in their [project pull requests](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/pull/1729). Angular esbuild does not have this fix, you can upgrade Angular to a higher version and hope it fixes the issue, or you can switch the builder to the default builder `application` since this will not have this issue.

[esbuild docs on Angular website](https://angular.io/guide/esbuild#for-existing-applications)